My HTML is updating correctly to change colour with tailwind, but the browser only actually updates with the colour gray, not other colours, why?
I'm using JS, to update the background colour of an HTML element using tailwind.
It works with the colour gray, but not any other colour.
If I change yellow or green with gray, they update correctly, if I change gray with another colour, it doesn't work correctly. So, the code is working fine, if I check console, it has the correct tailwind class, it's just that the browser is not updating the colour displayed, unless it's gray.
Any ideas why?
It also only updates with 200, so if it's bg-gray-200 it changes colour, but if it's anything else, it doesn't.
Code below:
 for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            let letterColour = 'yellow'
            let box = row.children[i]
            let letter = currentGuess[i]
            let letterPosition = correctWord.indexOf(currentGuess[i])
            console.log(letterPosition)

            if (letterPosition === -1) {
                letterColour = "gray"
                let colour = "red"
                colourKeyboard(letter, colour)
            }
            else if (currentGuess[i] === correctWord[i]) {
                letterColour = "green"
                let colour = "green"
                colourKeyboard(letter, colour)
            }
 
            let backgroundColour = `bg-${letterColour}-200`
            console.log(backgroundColour)
            box.classList.add(backgroundColour)
            console.log(box)
        }


Can you please add the relevant HTML, and the missing variable definitions in your JS, to the question

I found out it's a tailwind issue with dynamic class names.
Docs found here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names
Edit: with tailwind you can't use dynamic class names, for example: bg-{colour}-200.
You need to set your variable as the whole class. So set colour to be bg-green-200

This answer could be improved by adding more details instead of just a link. Links go dead over time.
